# How to change the color of black focus box in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am working with Eclipse. When clicking on a method, it usually asks us to p press F2 on to view the method details. However the text is black in color and so is the background. I have to end up selecting all of the contents to view them each time. Is there a way to make  the background plain white instead.

Comment: Here is the answer for Ubuntu (with detailed instructions):
http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

Comment: For fedora (kde) go system settings, search for color, in the 3rd tab color , pick tooltip (last in select box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the background color of that popup cannot be configured via the eclipse preference as it uses the operation system 's ToolTip  's background color .

For the widows OS , you can refer [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_5989202_change-tool-tip-color.html) to change the Tool Tip background  color

Answer (score 2):

You can change the focus window background color from
Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Source Hover Background

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution for this Go to Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> General->Appearance ->Colors and Fonts

Change the Javadoc Background Color and the Javadoc text Color as per your requirements , no need to change both though

Please find the attached screenshots for the same

ScreenShot1 : [Eclipse Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbP2o.png)

ScreenShot2 : [Impact of the Eclipse Settings Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu8jk.png)

Comment: This is the correct answer for Eclipse Oxygen. Changing the Windows 7 tool tip colors does nothing right now.